# Как записать TreeView по кускам в разные xml файлы?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Есть TreeView.

Как записать TreeViewItem-ы по кускам разные термины и подразделы в разные xml файлы?

TreeView выглядит так:

```
Компьютерная графика
  Термины
    2D
    3D
    Графика
    Компьютер
    Кадр
    Информатика
    Монитор
    Пиксель
  Подразделы
     3D графика
       Термины
        Графика  
        Мультипликация
        Космос 
        Человек  
        Модель
       Подразделы
         2D анимация
           Термины
            Изображение
            Коррекция кадра
            Титры
           Подразделы
             2,5 D
      CGI графика   
        Термины
          Цвета
          Типография
          RGB
          CMYK
        Подразделы
          Реальная сторона графики
```

Чтобы получилось примерно так:

a1.xml

```
<Razdel>Компьютерная графика</Razdel>
<TerminVRazdele> <Termin>Монитор</Termin> </TerminVRazdele>
<TerminVRazdele> <Termin>Пиксель</Termin> </TerminVRazdele>
<Podrazdeli> <Podrazdel>3D графика</Podrazdel> </Podrazdeli>
<Podrazdeli> <Podrazdel>CGI графика</Podrazdel> </Podrazdeli>
```

a1-1.xml

```
<Razdel>3D графика</Razdel>
<TerminVRazdele> <Termin>Графика</Termin> </TerminVRazdele>
<TerminVRazdele> <Termin>Мультипликация</Termin> </TerminVRazdele>
<Podrazdeli> <Podrazdel>2D анимация</Podrazdel> </Podrazdeli>
```

a1-1-1.xml

```
<Razdel>2D анимация</Razdel>
<TerminVRazdele> <Termin>Изображение</Termin> </TerminVRazdele>
<TerminVRazdele> <Termin>Коррекция кадра</Termin> </TerminVRazdele>
<TerminVRazdele> <Termin>Титры</Termin> </TerminVRazdele>
<Podrazdeli> <Podrazdel>2,5 D</Podrazdel> </Podrazdeli>
```

Answer (score 1):

У TreeView нет метода записи в xml файл, да и вообще в любой другой формат. Поэтому в любом случае метод придется писать самому. Самый простой по моему мнению - это переводить нужные ветки TreeView в DataTable, а у DataTable уже есть стандартный метод записи в формат XML

Answer (score 1):

Еще никто не отменял обычный способ записи в файл. Считывайте Node и Items из дерева, и пишите в файл (построчно), а затем сохраняйте в требующимся формате.

Comment: Как пробовал сделал несколько циклов for в начале в 1 файл записывается нормально в другие одинаковые строки записываются при записи подразделов в глубину не считывает. Как сделать чтобы записывал подразделы правильно?

Comment: Можно и DataTable суть не важна каким методом писать главное содержимое файлов чтобы было как в примере пока получается только один файл

Comment: Есть ли какие-нибудь приммеры по данному вопросу в инете ничего не нашёл

Comment: Обходи в цикле все узлы дерева, и выбирай данные! Наизусть не помню, тем более суббота, вечер :) Но доступ к элементам TreeView есть в любом справочном руководстве! Сам формируй теги XML, под них вставляй данные дерева - и все! Так делали отчеты в формате HTML, выбрали данные и пошли писать, что-то вроде этого WriteLn ("<p>" + Value+ "</p>"). Язык программирования не имеет значения.

Comment: Я практически так и делаю. На этапе обхода дочерних это и происходит. Только у меня каждый раз TreeViewItem должен иметь новое значение, а он получает старое значение и его записывает в файл.

Comment: Решили данный вопрос? А то давно не заходил сюда... А тут комменты, комменты...